# Most occuring text value with criteria. MODE doesn't work

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling with function to output most occuring value in a range that ignores two values (` and -)

```
=INDEX(Download_1[01.12.2020];MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Download_1[01.12.2020];Download_1[01.12.2020]));COUNTIF(Download_1[01.12.2020];Download_1[01.12.2020]);0))
```

Right now it outputs "`", which is true but I want to skip this value and another "-" to provide 3rd most occuring one.

I've tried different formulas with MODE but they don't seem to work on text values in a range. Can you help me modify the formula or provide a new one?

Answer (score 2):

For me the following works including `MODE()`:

[image]

Formula in `B1` using a nested `IF()`:

```
=INDEX(A1:A13,MODE(IF(A1:A15<>"`",IF(A1:A15<>"-",MATCH(A1:A15,A1:A15,0)))))
```

Or using a boolean structure:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MODE(IF((A1:A15<>"`")*(A1:A15<>"-"),MATCH(A1:A15,A1:A15,0))))
```

---

**Note**: This is an array formula which need to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> if you don't have Microsoft365.